# Is there any way I can integrate Minitube with a web browser like Chrome?

Tags: minitube

I really enjoy using [Minitube[image: Install Minitube]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minitube-ubuntu/). It's a very comfortable and lightweight alternative to YouTube playback with flash. The only thing that bothers me is that I have to manually copy and paste interesting youtube links I found into the program to play them back.

Is there any way I can automate this and integrate Minitube into Google Chrome or another web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Integrating Minitube with Chrome using a Chrome extension

---

**Overview**

Thanks to a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minitube/cakooiidafjonhmkfcpidiiapekfgdfe) by Nicu Farmache this is now possible. The extension source code may be checked out at the [google code project page](https://code.google.com/p/minitube-chrome-extension/).

**Installation**

While trying to install the extension I found that the instructions provided by the author weren't working for me on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. These are the steps I followed to get it to work anyway:

1. Install the extension from the Chrome Webstore
2. Create a script called `minitubehandler.sh` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # NAME:         minitubehandler.sh
   # VERSION:      
   # AUTHOR:       (c) 2013 Glutanimate
   # DESCRIPTION:  - parses youtube links coming from the Chrome minitube extension
   # FEATURES:     
   # DEPENDENCIES: minitube-ubuntu
   #
   # LICENSE:      GNU GPL v3
   #
   # USAGE:        Please follow the instructions provided in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/353176/81372)

   MINITUBEURL="$1"
   ACTUALURL="${MINITUBEURL#minitube}"
   MINITUBE="/opt/minitube-ubuntu/minitube"

   "$MINITUBE" "$ACTUALURL" > /dev/null 2>&1&
   ```

   Please note that this will only work with the `minitube-ubuntu` package installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. In order to use the script with other version of `minitube` you will have to edit the path to the minitube executable.
3. Either move the script to $PATH (e.g. `~/bin` ) or move it to a folder of your choice and copy down the file path
4. Create a new desktop file under `~/.local/share/applications` called `minitubehandler.desktop` with the following contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/minitubehttp;x-scheme-handler/minitubehttps;
   Terminal=false
   Exec=minitubehandler.sh %u
   Name=minitubehandler
   Icon=minitube
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
5. Make sure to replace the `Exec` line with the path to your script if you decided against moving it to your `$PATH`
6. Assign the desktop file to the extension's MIME type by executing the following lines in a terminal:

   ```
   xdg-mime default minitubehandler.desktop x-scheme-handler/minitubehttp

   xdg-mime default minitubehandler.desktop x-scheme-handler/minitubehttps
   ```
7. Restart Chrome

From now on if you navigate to a YouTube video page you should see a small Minitube icon on the right side of your address bar:

[image]

Clicking it will launch Minitube and play back the video or - if Minitube is already running - switch playback to the video in question:

[image]